# vertical align fontawesome inside td element

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have an `<i>` element with fontawesome icon inside `<td>` I want it to be vertically centered

here a screenshot:

[image]

here my html:

```
<tbody>
....
   <tr>
      <td style="word-wrap: break-word;min-width: 480px;max-width: 480px;">
         <i style="margin-right: 8px; vertical-align : middle;" class="fa fa-folder"></i>
         <h2 style="width:93%; white-space: pre-wrap; ">cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</h2>
      </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `line-height: inherit` property on `fa-folder`?

Comment: Can you show your css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use `flexbox` inside the `<td>`:**

```
td {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) to adjust it vertically for example:

```
line-height: 10px;
```

or use negative to elevate it up

```
line-height: -10px;
```